# NodeJS: Typescript export expressjs from wrapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, npm

I've created an ExpressJS wrapper on private npm repo and i want export my lib and expressjs itself, eg.:

index.ts

```
export { myExpress } from './my-express'; // my express wrapper
import * as express from 'express';
export = express; // doesn't works!
```

how can i make it in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Express 4 is that it uses deprecated CommonJS export convention that isn't compatible with ES modules, it contains the only export (`express()` factory), the rest of exports are defined as its properties. It uses legacy TypeScript `export = ...` syntax, so it cannot be re-exported as ES module `export * from 'express'`, also cannot make use of synthetic default re-export, `export { default } from 'express'`.

Given the module should re-export an export from `express` and `myExpress` export from `./my-express`, it should be:

```
import * as express from 'express';
export default express;

export { myExpress } from './my-express';
```

It can be imported as:

```
import express, { myExpress } from '...';
```

For regular ES module, `*` could be re-exported:

```
export * from 'some-package';
export { myExport } from './my-package';
```

Comment: `export * from 'express';` raise ts error `[ts] Module '"index"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.`

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Indeed, the module contains legacy exports. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `export = express;` syntax isn't correct.

You'll want to do either:

```
import { myExpress } from './my-express';
import * as express from 'express';

export {
  myExpress,
  express
}
```

or

```
import { myExpress } from './my-express';
export { myEpxress }

import * as express from 'express';
export { express }
```